# I get an error with the npm run ios command

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

When I write this command 'npm run ios' I get this error:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening PhotoSearch.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Zocial.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Zocial.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Octicons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Octicons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Octicons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialIcons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialIcons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Ionicons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Ionicons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Foundation.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Foundation.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Foundation.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Fontisto.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Fontisto.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Fontisto.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Feather.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Feather.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Feather.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/EvilIcons.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/EvilIcons.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/EvilIcons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Entypo.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Entypo.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Entypo.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/AntDesign.ttf':
1) Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch') has copy command from '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/AntDesign.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'PhotoSearch' (project 'PhotoSearch'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'react-native-orientation' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/AntDesign.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Entypo.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/EvilIcons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Feather.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Fontisto.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Foundation.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Ionicons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/MaterialIcons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Octicons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/SimpleLineIcons.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.app/Zocial.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/front.end.af/Documents/Nikita/kinoagenstvo/ios/build/PhotoSearch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PhotoSearch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoSearch.build/Script-97FA921B89C00DA950E1ACE1.sh (in target 'PhotoSearch' from project 'PhotoSearch')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'RSKImageCropper' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'react-native-viewpager' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'RNImageRotate' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same bug when i installed `react-native-vector-icons` package. This issue is related to the autolinking feature on React Native 0.60+

Open the project into XCode (by opening the .xcworkspace file if you have used CocoaPods or the .xcodeproj file); in the main application tab, look for the **Build Phases** tab (between Build Setting and Build Rules); open the section **Copy Bundle Resources** and manually remove all the fonts listed into the error.

Be careful to not touch the **[CP] Copy Pods Resources** section because you can find the fonts inside that section too!